# Is "put ~ at ease" compatible with "with"?

Tags: phrases

I can say "I'm at ease with something".
And I think "put ~ at ease" consists of "put" and "at ease".

Then, can I say "somebody put me at ease with something"? Or can't I use "with" in this case?

Comment: Do you mean to be made comfortable **by** something, e.g. _I was worried about flying but she put me at ease with her kindness and reassuring manner_ or to made comfortable **about** something e.g. _she put me at ease with her marriage by mentioning how rich her husband was_? In either case, the answer is 'yes'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct English in my opinion. But I think its more common, among English speakers, to say

> [put|set] [my|his|her|etc] *mind* at ease.

For example

> Let me set your mind at ease. I'm 100% sure that the damage will be fully covered by your insurance policy.